# How not to SELECT in MySQL duplicates of rows

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL table as follow:

```
| id | seller | type |
|  1 |  345   |  AB  |
|  3 |  234   |  CD  |
|  7 |  345   |  AB  |
| 10 |  234   |  AB  |
```

In this example, I have duplicates of id 1 and 7 and I need to return only one of them.
So I am running following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
ORDER BY seller, type ASC;
```

Which gives me table:

```
| id | seller | type |
| 10 |  234   |  AB  |
|  3 |  234   |  CD  |
|  1 |  345   |  AB  |
|  7 |  345   |  AB  |
```

When I run following query with GROUP BY type:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    ORDER BY seller, type ASC
     ) AS T1
GROUP BY T1.type;
```

I am going to get only two records.

My solution would be to create additional column with "unique_ID" which would be combination of seller and type and then GROUP BY unique_ID.
But I was wondering if there is another approach.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try SELECT DISTINCT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` group by `seller` , `type`
```

It's output will be :-

```
    +----+--------+------+
    | id | seller | type |
    +----+--------+------+
    | 10 |  234   |  AB  |
    |  3 |  234   |  CD  |
    |  1 |  345   |  AB  |
    +----+--------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT MIN(id),seller, type  
FROM table1 
GROUP BY seller, type
```